# Specific function to onblur of several elements

Tags: jquery, function, bind

I have a function that checks the input and it works well.

```
function checkInputNumber() {
    var 
        inputNumber = $(this).val(),  
        dotsCount = 0,
        i;   
for(i = 0; i < inputNumber.length; i++) { 
    if( (inputNumber[i].charCodeAt() >= 48 && inputNumber[i].charCodeAt(0) <= 57) ||  
(inputNumber[i].charCodeAt(0) == 46)) {
            if((inputNumber[i].charCodeAt(0) == 46)) {
                dotsCount++;
                if(dotsCount > 1) {
                     $(this).val(""); 
                }
            }  
        }  
    }         
}
```

AND I want to add it to different elements on their "blur" property :

```
 $('#input1').bind('blur', checkInputNumber());
 $('#input2').bind('blur', checkInputNumber());
```

but I'm not sure about the syntax. Any ideas/suggestions ?

Comment: $("#input").blur(function(){
  checkInputNumber();
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#input1, #input2').on('blur', checkInputNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

remove those `()`

```
$('#input1').bind('blur', checkInputNumber);
$('#input2').bind('blur', checkInputNumber);
```